# Setting up mTurk CLI, permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, osx-yosemite, mechanicalturk

Setting up mrturk CLI on my **Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10**, Permission is denied when I try to access `mturk.properties` file even though I have proper access keys.  HEre is what I've run through terminal (user name removed):

> User-MacBook-Pro-2:~ $
>   /Users/Downloads/aws-mturk-clt-1.3.1/bin/mturk.properties 
>   -bash: /Users/Downloads/aws-mturk-clt-1.3.1/bin/mturk.properties: Permission denied

I believe this is the problem that is interferring with what I ultiamtely want to run, here's my terminal code:

> User-MacBook-Pro-2:~ $ /Users/Downloads/aws-mturk-clt-1.3.1 
>   -bash: /Users/Downloads/aws-mturk-clt-1.3.1: is a directory User-MacBook-Pro-2:~ $ export
>   MTURK_CMD_HOME=/users/downloads/aws-mturk-clt-1.3.1
>
> User-MacBook-Pro-2:~ $ export
>   JAVA_HOME=/System/Library?Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home
>   User-MacBook-Pro-2:~ $ export
>   PATH=$PATH:/users/downloads/aws-mturk-clt-1.3.1/bin
>
> User-MacBook-Pro-2:~ $
>   users/downloads/aws-mturk-clt-1.3.1/bin/getBalance.sh
>   -bash: users/downloads/aws-mturk-clt-1.3.1/bin/getBalance.sh: No such file or directory

THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!  I'm going to bash my skull in with this keyboard.